# How to getDuration() with/without MediaPlayer

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have two Fragments in my ViewPager. The 1st fragment lists down all the mp3 files that are available and the second one actually does the playing (implements the MediaPlayer logic).

In my 1st fragment I would like to list out the duration of the mp3 files. Because all the mp3 files are being loaded from media files how do I get the duration of them files ?

I tried the following:

**Initial declaration:**

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
```

**Code Implementation:**

```
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(mp3URL);
totalDuration = utils.milliSecondsToTimer(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
```

`MilliSecondsToTimer` converts the `milliseconds` string to `3:40` format.

**Final Application:**

```
duration.setText(totalDuration);
```

Doing this gives me the following error:

```
10-08 03:38:03.341: E/MediaPlayer(2586): Attempt to call getDuration without a valid mediaplayer
10-08 03:38:03.361: E/MediaPlayer(2586): error (-38, 0)
10-08 03:38:03.461: E/MediaPlayer(2586): Error (-38,0)
```

How do I just extract the total duration from the URL ?? Help please.

Answer (score 0):

You might be calling getDuration before the file is fully loaded. See if the solution to this question works for you.

```
final VideoView video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoplayer);
            final MediaController controller = new MediaController(this);

            video.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(getIntent().getStringExtra("url")));
            video.setMediaController(controller);
            controller.setMediaPlayer(video);
            video.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

                   public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                       int duration = video.getDuration();
                       video.requestFocus();
                       video.start();
                       controller.show();

                   }
               });
```

Comment: how do i fully load the file ? Do i call the onPreparedListener ?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get `mediaPlayer.getDuration()` before the preparation is complete. Use the `setOnPreparedListener()` method to set a preparation listener and call the `getDuration()` method only after the preparation is complete.

```
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
  public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
      totalDuration = utils.milliSecondsToTimer(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
  }
});
```

Comment: I am getting an `IllegalStateException` - attachNewPlayer called in state 2 error!